# Broken pipe "works" differently in different terminal emulators?

Tags: bash, terminal-emulator

When I try to run the same command `find . | head -n 5` in two different terminal emulators, st and lilyterm, both on the same Debian 10 system, I get different results:

1. lilyterm prints 5 lines as expected without delays and errors
2. st prints 5 lines, waits some time and also prints the error

```
find: 'standard output': Broken pipe
find: write error
```

I cannot understand why it happens and how to fix it in st. I use the same shell (bash) in both terminals.

It is quite annoying when working with fzf.

UPD:
I also tested it with `yes`. In st I have

```
$ yes | head -n 3
y
y
y
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
$
```

while in lilyterm I have

```
$ yes | head -n 3
y
y
y
$
```

Comment: Are you in the same directory each time you try this?

Comment: @roaima Yes, I am in my home directory.

Comment: Does it also happen if you start it as `st -e bash`? Also try with `st -e bash --norc`. And `st -e bash -x` and look for any `trap '' PIPE`

Comment: @pizdelect
I tried to start st as `st -e bash` and `st -e bash --norc`, it works the same. And it looks like there is no something like `trap '' PIPE` in output of `st -e bash -x`.

Maybe it is interesting that xterm works as st i.e `yes | head -n 3` produces an broken pipe error, while virtual consoles (to which I can switch by Ctrl-Alt-Fn) works well.

Comment: So it's your window manager (or whatever app/menu/file manager you're starting st from) which is ignoring the PIPE signal (and st and the shell are inheriting the disposition). lilyterm is probably resetting it to default. That's a bug in the window manager -- it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @pizdelect
It looks like you are right. I start st from dwm, it works fine. Thank you very much! I am new here, so I don't know how to mark your comment as an answer.

Am I right that it happens because my window manager handle somehow the signal SIGPIPE and launch the terminal by fork, so terminal has the same handler that WM (maybe empty)?

Comment: @pizdelect Care to write an answer?